# Calculate position of sun in sky

Tags: the-sun, horizon

I would like to calculate the angle formed by the sun and the horizon for any hour of the day and any day of the year for a particular place on Earth.  So like: what is the angle of the sun to the horizon at 11AM on June 21 at Chicago?  (Sorry, I'm a newbie, and don't even know what the name of this angle is).  Is there a formula for calculating this?  Thanks!

Comment: Here's [a calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1224682277) that finds the elevation angle of the Sun for a given place and time. Works for years 1900–2099, though. [Another calculator](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/solcalc/azel.html) doesn't seem to set a limit on the year. _Solar elevation_ is the name for the angle you want to know

Comment: The formulas needed are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun

Comment: @YellowSky I think your comments have enough material for a proper answer.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.